# Product2 record creation

Tags: create-records

I have a weird scenario.

I am creating new product2 records in batch and setting the isactive checkbox to true.
After insertion when i debug, it says it is set to true.
But when i go to that record, it is not checked.
I even queried and saw the results, it is set to false.

But the debug log says it's set to true.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue, there was a workflow that i over looked. Its disabling the isactive check box after records are created.

I added a recordtype condition in workflow rule criteria and it solved the problem.